# Android Marshmallow : activity recreates after permission granted

Tags: android, android-fragments, permissions, runtime-permissions

So when i call requestContactPermission method, the dialog appears normally but when i click on allow button , the fragment close and the activity forced to recreate ? what seems to be the problem ? the log dose not show anything

```
   private void requestContactPermission() {

        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    101);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

my main problem is when i test it in emulator its works fine but when i test it in real device, like Galaxy S7 edge i'm having this problem

Comment: Ask for permission early, i prefer asking it in the `Activity` you are having this fragment

Comment: @Sanoop already tried it, same result

Comment: Ok.. Is the `Activity` you are asking permission in.. Is the main or default `Activity` if not ask for permission in the `MainActivity`.. By doing so you ll only need to check permission in `onCreateView` of fragment.. So the `Activity` won't re-create...

Comment: Give it a try.. If still problem persists.. Will dig deeper..

Answer (score 0):

**Give this a try.**

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Runtime Permission Read contact");

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    101);
        } else {

      Log.d(TAG, "Previously User have provided Read contact access");

        }


 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 101: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Write External Storage Access granted");

                    downloadCurrentImage();

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.

                } else {


                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```